# How to create a district or school?

Tags: google-classroom

It does not seem like Google Classroom gives the ability to create a school or district.

I have been tasked to add this platform to one of our application that pull data from various Student Information System.

So I would like to know if there are any notion of school or district within `Google Classroom`.

The only entities I see are, student, teachers and course, but this is not enough from me to process a district.

Please advise.

Comment: Stack Overflow cannot provide technical support for products like Google Classroom.

Comment: Ok so where to ask, and why is the tag available

Comment: It may be relevant to programming within the context of using an API. There's bound to be a forum, Google Group for this, or even [Quora](http://quora.com).

Comment: Tadman I get what you are saying, but even google says to ask the question on stackoverflow, see the bottom of [docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/). we all know quora is not for programmers

Comment: If you're asking a question here it has to pertain to programming, so if you're just using the Google Classroom API then it's important to include the relevant code in your question. The way this is phrased is too generic, it's basically asking about the inner workings of a Google product. Quora is great for questions that aren't overly technical. Dumping code on Quora is a mistake, same as not including code on Stack Overflow causes problems.

Comment: yes there is no code involved with this question but it is still programming related, hopefully someone from google classroom team can shade some light or point me to the right docs where this API call is found

Answer (score 1):

This feature doesn't exist in [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started) yet. You can either make your own workaround by writing your own code implementation or try filing a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: In other words, the short answer is "No" - that feature is not available.